# Is "here I googled it for you, please google this topic for more information" the best quality answers we can give?

Tags: discussion

In my recent question here:

[What advancements towards Mars were made during Scott Kelly and Mikhail Kornienko's "1 year" journey?](https://space.stackexchange.com/questions/14330/what-advancements-towards-mars-were-made-during-scott-kelly-and-mikhail-kornienk)

2 answers have come in yet to me they read like: "I googled some stuff which I will quote here and by the way there is a thing called google and that's how I was able to come up with such a good answer because I know of google and if you want more elaboration on the subject well good luck because google can find it because there is no way you can find it here what are you thinking, haven't you heard of google?"

Forgive my dramatic flair but is that the best we can expect as question askers? LMGTFY? As a question answerer even though the question may seem simple and googleable to you, I think there needs to be reasonable doubt given to the question asker that they may have googled and did not find what they were looking for and thus came to this forum for enlightenment that the question answerer is capable of giving respectfully.

Comment: LMGTFY in action looks like a single link with a sentence or two to go with it, mostly talking about how simple it was. It does *not* look like 3-10 paragraphs of original answer, each, plus quotes.

Answer (score 6):

The answers have quite a bit more information than just a link. I suppose you went to the links provided and looked around. Then you must have seen what was summarized very briefly for you - this project has a large team on it from a number of medical fields, who are actually still collecting data, and won't be able to analyze it, draw conclusions, and publish those for a number of months. If that had been done it *might* be possible to squeeze those results down into a short list that briefly explains their significance, but it wouldn't be easy. You are asking for that before there even are any results. And this field of health is so new even then it will be very hard to say much about what it ultimately means. Just because you know how many strands of DNA were damaged over a year on the ISS doesn't mean you can say how that will tend to affect people's health down the road, or if it is similar to such effects in other places in space, or if that amount of damage was a typical result. This is a long term project where we are collecting the most basic data needed to start to understand it.

It would be easy to argue that your question deserves to be closed as too broad, because to answer it well would take more space than Stack Exchange is designed for. But, when people ask beginner questions from an innocent standpoint, sometimes it is more useful to write up an answer that gives a very general overview. General overviews are often really hard to write well. This one is especially so.